# Is there an "identity" (or "no-op") environment that simply uses its contents unaltered?

Tags: macros, environments

In the functional programming paradigm, it is common to have functions accept other functions as parameters. This paradigm can be followed in LaTeX, too: A macro can accept parameters which themselves can be macros or environment names. For this use case, the equivalent of an "identity function" is missing in LaTeX: A macro and an environment that behaves as if it wasn't there.

Basically, I am looking for something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{identity}{}{}
\begin{identity}
  This will be parsed as if not surrounded by anything.
\end{identity}
\end{document}
```

I'm reluctant to define this environment if something similar already exists in standard LaTeX or in any "standard" package. How is "identity" called in LaTeX?

Comment: This is not really "identity", because it encloses the contents in a group. But there's nothing of this kind in the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: From the text in your environment: do you really mean "without being changed" because if so that sounds more like  the `verbatim` environment.

Comment: Because `\begin{foo}` uses `\foo` and `\end{foo}` uses `\endfoo` if it exists, it is OK but usually not recommend to use a macro name as environment, i.e. you could simply use `\begin{relax} .. \end{relax}` or `\begin{empty} .. \end{empty}` and take advantage of `\relax` and `\empty`. Both are basically no-op macros, which `\empty` expands to nothing but `\relax` is not expandable and represents a lower-level no-op.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: No, I don't mean verbatim. I'll edit.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Thanks. The `empty` environment works for me, `relax` didn't work as LaTeX complained that `\endrelax` is undefined.

Comment: @user946850: Ok, but the error should be `! LaTeX Error: Environment relax undefined.` not about `\endrelax`. The reason is that the used test can't differ between undefined and `\relax`, so it fails for `\relax`. I should have thought that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to egreg's answer:

You can make the environment more transparent if you cancel the group it adds.
However, you need to define the environment name in the end-code to make the end-test happy. Note that this will not give you a correct warning message if you use either `\begin{identity}` or `\end{identity}` without the other. Instead you will get a different environment name in the warning message.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{identity}
    {\endgroup\ignorespaces}
    {\begingroup\def\@currenvir{identity}\ignorespacesafterend}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand\test{Grouping!}

\begin{identity}

    Some text ...
    \renewcommand\test{No Grouping!}

    This is the environment ``\csname @currenvir\endcsname''.
    %\tracingonline=1
    %\showgroups
\end{identity}

Grouping? \test

\end{document}
```

The test file shows that there is no effective grouping for the content.

Comment: Lovely. -- Am I the first who needs this functionality? Perhaps we can package this, and add an `\identity` command, too?

Comment: @user946850: there is already `\@firstofone` which is like `\identity` but has a `@` in its name :-(. I can package it if you want. Can you give some information about your exact use case for a descriptive summary?

Comment: "In the functional programming paradigm, it is common to have functions accept other functions as parameters. This paradigm can be followed in \LaTeX, too: A macro can accept parameters which themselves can be macros or environment names. For this use case, the equivalent of an ``identity function'' is missing in \LaTeX: A macro and an environment that behaves as if it wasn't there. This package defines the `\verb!\identity!` command and the `\verb!identity!` environment to be used as parameters for macros that accept macros or environment names." -- Something along these lines?

Answer (score 11):

There's not a predefined environment that does nothing. You can emulate it with

```
\begin{empty}
Text
\end{empty}
```

but this will add unwanted spaces. So probably

```
\newenvironment{identity}
  {\ignorespaces}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}
```

would be what you need. Beware that this will add a level of grouping so it's not *really* "do nothing".

Comment: I have completely forgotten about the extra spaces. Thank you!