# Solution environment via true/false switch

Tags: environments

I would like to create a solution environment that prints a solution in the case
where an optional argument is set to true (the default) and hides the solution
in the case that the argument is false. I tried to use egreg's idea from
[Is there an "identity" (or "no-op") environment that simply uses its contents unaltered?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58017/is-there-an-identity-or-no-op-environment-that-simply-uses-its-contents-un)
but my construction already fails due to the optional argument (`Illegal parameter number in definition of \endsolution`). The idea would be to not show anything (ideally no
vertical space would be created either) if we are in the ``false'' case.

Note: I'm aware of other solutions to this problem (see [Comparing packages which facilitate typesetting exercises and solutions: exercise vs. answers vs. probsoln](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22269/comparing-packages-which-facilitate-typesetting-exercises-and-solutions-exercis)) but I am interested to see what I am doing wrong in my construction.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

% solution environment
\newenvironment{solution}[1][true]{
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{#1}}{\par{\sffamily\bfseries Solution}\par}{\ignorespaces}
}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{#1}}{}{\ignorespacesafterend}}

\begin{document}
This is Exercise 1 with solution.
\begin{solution}
  Solution to Exercise 1
\end{solution}

\bigskip
This is Exercise 2 (without solution).
\begin{solution}[false]
  This should not appear.
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can't use arguments for an environment in the end statement - there's a way round this using `xparse`; [Why can't the end code of an environment contain an argument?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17036) and [Passing \newenvironment parameters to the end block?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20576)

Comment: I know you want an answer to your question, but you should have a look at the `exsheets` package; it truly is great.

Comment: Thanks, I agree, this is the best package I have seen so far for such tasks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arguments passed to an environment are not available in the code that is executed at the end. You can get around this by saving them using global declarations in the initialisation code. Also, there is nothing in your example to prevent the body of the environment (i.e. between `\begin{solution}` and `\end{solution}`) from being processed in the false case. You can do this using the [environ package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ). In this code, the body of the environment is only processed when the `\BODY` macro is executed.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{environ}

% solution environment
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{solution}[1][true]{
  \gdef\@tmp{#1}
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{#1}}{\par{\sffamily\bfseries Solution}\par\BODY}{\ignorespaces}
}[\ifthenelse{\boolean{\@tmp}}{}{\ignorespacesafterend}]
\makeatother    

\begin{document}
This is Exercise 1 with solution.
\begin{solution}
  Solution to Exercise 1
\end{solution}

\bigskip
This is Exercise 2 (without solution).
\begin{solution}[false]
  This should not appear.
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply + good explanations.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question here (how to use `\RenewEnviron` instead of `\NewEnviron`): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173645/how-to-generalize-a-solution-with-newenviron-to-renewenviron-error-envproo

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution using the [`xparse`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xparse) package, and its `NewDocumentEnvironment` which allows the use of arguments in the `\end{environment}` code.

The important part is

```
% solution environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{solution}{O{true}}{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{#1}}{\par{\sffamily\bfseries Solution}\par}{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}
    }{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{#1}}{}{\egroup}
}
```

Here's a complete MWE to play with; see [Why can't the end code of an environment contain an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17036/why-cant-the-end-code-of-an-environment-contain-an-argument) and [Passing \newenvironment parameters to the end block?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20576/passing-newenvironment-parameters-to-the-end-block) for further reference.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ifthen}

% solution environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{solution}{O{true}}{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{#1}}{\par{\sffamily\bfseries Solution}\par}{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}
    }{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{#1}}{}{\egroup}
}

\begin{document}
This is Exercise 1 with solution.
\begin{solution}
    Solution to Exercise 1
\end{solution}

\bigskip
This is Exercise 2 (without solution).
\begin{solution}[false]
    This should not appear.
\end{solution}

\begin{solution}[true]
    This *should*  appear.
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use `\vbox` which allows paragraphs, not `\hbox`.

Comment: @cmhughes: I would like to use `\usepackage{ifthen}` and define a global variable `\newboolean{sol}`. I set it to false `\setboolean{sol}{false}` and `sol` should be the default for the solution environment, how would one incorporate this? If I use `...{solution}{O{sol}}{...` it gives me an error.

Comment: @egreg: I realized a problem with (both `\hbox` and) `\vbox`. See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173128/floats-lost-in-newly-defined-environment-possible-vbox-hbox-problem

Comment: @MariusHofert Yes, of course, if you're devious enough to use the `figure` environment in a proof. `;-)` My proposal for the last question of yours can be easily adapted, I believe. My objection was that `\hbox` can't work if there is more than simple text and will fail with lists and other things.

Comment: @egreg :-) Thanks. Do you know a solution to the problem? Most solution manual contain figures (for better understanding). I like the approach based on `xparse`, but if I can't use a figure inside a solution environment, this would be quite a drawback

Comment: @MariusHofert Doesn't Ian Thompson's solution work?

Comment: It does, I was just looking for a more elegant way via xparse (due to some other consistencies as well). So I probably just use that.